# VB.Net Coding Errors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So as part of my college work, I've been working on a game and game splash program with a functional combat system. This is being done in Visual Studio, however, I have a problem.

Whenever you're set to engage in combat, I am given this error:
http://prntscr.com/duswke

Here is the code which is resulting in the error:

```
    Console.WriteLine("You have arrived at the " & Place(randomNum) & " aboard your ship")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Console.WriteLine("You look around to check for hostiles...")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

    Enemy(1) = "An enemy runs towards you and  engages with you in combat!"
    Enemy(2) = "You see nothing around you but stars, It's all clear"

    Randomize()
    randomNum2 = Int(Int((2 * Rnd()) + 1))

    Console.WriteLine("" & Enemy(randomNum2) & "")

    If Enemy(1) Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Console.Clear()
        Call Sub() Combat()
    ElseIf Enemy(2) Then
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("You have found some treasure deep within the " & Place(randomNum) & " ")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Console.WriteLine("Continue Adventuring?")

  Console.Clear()
        Call Sub() Combat()
    End If
```

Basically whats supposed to happen is its supposed to clear console and open up the combat menu (  Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("1 - Attack")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("2 - Inventory")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("3 - Run")
        Console.WriteLine() )
and once that is open, using the chrMenu Char, you should be able to select and execute and option, it however stops at "If Enemy(1) which it should not. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen at `If Enemy(1) Then`?

Comment: Is this VB.NET or something?  It definitely doesn't look like C#

Comment: It helps if you know what you're coding in to start with. It's definitely not C#. It's VB.NET. Think it would be wise to learn a little more and do smaller chunks.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) and set it as the default for new projects. It will help you greatly in producing working code.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this:

```
If Enemy(1) Then
```

because the item at position 1 is:

```
Enemy(1) = "An enemy runs towards you and  engages with you in combat!"
```

That is a string. The condition in an if statement has to produce a `True` or `False` value.

So perhaps you want to check if the value is equal to something and then do something. Like this:

```
If Enemy(1) = "Something you want to compare it to" Then
    ' Do Something here
End If
```

Comment: I think he meant to write If (randomnum2 = 1) then . . .

Comment: I have no idea peterG but he/she clearly needs help with if branches and thus I tried to mention that in my answer. But ya maybe ;)